# Don't confuse me with the one about chickens!

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> Pain is what I will attack you with,
> A plague that appears once, what a myth.
>
> In your throat I'll sequester,
> Now in your hands I'll fester.
>
> For if you see me lying around,
> Unbelievable pain will take you down.
>
> Let's, not forget, if I touch you, you can't run away.

What am I?

Hint

> You may get hot around me,
> Your hands and feet will plea.

Hint 2:

> A disease commonly found in children,
> Sores will most always afflict them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit: you are actually

> Coxsackie Virus (hand foot and mouth)

Pain is what I will attack you with,
A plague that appears once, what a myth.

> A painful disease, especially for adults

In your throat I'll sequester, Now in your hands I'll fester.

> Coxsackie starts its infection in the throat then moves to the skin

For if you see me lying around, Unbelievable pain will take you down.

> This disease keeps you from walking when it spreads to your feet

Let's, not forget, if I touch you, you can't run away.

> you can barely walk, nevermind run with this disease

Title: Don't confuse me with the one about chickens!

> Not to be confused with chicken-pox

fun (not fun) bonus: I've had this. It's awful.

---

Original Answer:

Are you

> Smallpox?

Pain is what I will attack you with,
A plague that appears once, what a myth.

> Smallpox is a painful disease which spreads like a plague

In your throat I'll sequester, Now in your hands I'll fester.

> Smallpox starts its infection in the throat then moves to the skin

For if you see me lying around, Unbelievable pain will take you down.

> Possibly a reference to 'smallpox blankets' in American history.  Once touched, the painful disease was easily communicable

Let's, not forget, if I touch you, you can't run away.

> Once you have the germs, you can not get away from the disease

Title: Don't confuse me with the one about chickens!

> Not to be confused with chicken-pox, a much less serious disease

Comment: Although everything seems to fit, I kinda hope you are wrong; if this is the intended answer, the question would fit webMD better than PSE.

Comment: This isn't the intended answer, though it is a good fit and you are on the right track.

Comment: Really? I thought TBO had nailed it, especially with the title :-)

Comment: TBO is close, but it's not this answer.

Comment: Hmm, how close am I?  Like, is the answer rot(pbjcbk)? Or do I need to think a little more outside the pox?

Comment: You're pretty darn close, though it's not rot(pbjcbk). Definitely think outside the pox, but not too far outside. I would look at the hints a little more carefully.

Comment: I suspect the answer is rot13([fuvatyrf](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/shingles/symptoms-causes/syc-20353054)), which is caused by the same virus as rot13(puvpxra cbk).

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Sorry, but that's not right either. Like I told TBO, think outside the pox.

Comment: I was thinking rot13(oynpx cynthr)

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Not quite. I would have mentioned something about rats or death or posies If I did a riddle about that.

Comment: One more guess in the comments before I fully elaborate: is it rot(Pbkfnpxvr ivehf)?

Comment: @TwoBitOperation, yes it is.

Comment: Excellent edit, I've marked it as the right answer. One piece of advise, I'd put the correct answer on top. I almost missed this edit.

Comment: Wow, good answer! I also had thought of your first guess, but the second...

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Bruise

Pain is what I will attack you with,
A plague that appears once, what a myth.

> You get a bruise after you hit yourself on something, which causes pain.

In your throat I'll sequester,
Now in your hands I'll fester.

> I am not sure about this but you can get a bruise in you hand.

For if you see me lying around,
Unbelievable pain will take you down.

> Bruise's can hurt.

Let's, not forget, if I touch you, you can't run away.

> Bruise's do not move until they get better.

Comment: It's not this either. But nice guess.

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Pac-Man Ghost

Pain is what I will attack you with,
A plague that appears once, what a myth.

> 255 levels of attacking, painful ghosts

In your throat I'll sequester,

> The death animation suggests jaw-unhinging, possibly throat based damage

Now in your hands I'll fester.

> Arcade joysticks are tough on the hands

For if you see me lying around,
Unbelievable pain will take you down.

> Get close enough to see the ghost and painful mouth expansion into nothingness ensues

Let's, not forget, if I touch you, you can't run away.

> A touch by the ghost ends Pac-Man's fleeing

Comment: No the answer is much closer to TBO's answer

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are

> Streptococcus (warning: I tried to pick links below without terrifying pictures above the fold, but follow them at your own risk)

Pain is what I will attack you with,

> Strep infections are painful.

A plague that appears once, what a myth.

> Unlike many viral infections, you can get the same bacterial infection again.

In your throat I'll sequester,

> Some strains of strep are common in the upper-respiratory tract, and [carriers of Group A strep (the kind that causes strep throat) can have "dormant" bacteria in their pharynx](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK374206/).

Now in your hands I'll fester.

> [Hand washing is one of the most important ways to avoid strep infection](https://www.huffingtonpost.ca/2013/12/27/how-long-can-germs-live_n_4509419.html), as touching something with strep bacteria on it (like a doorknob) and then touching your face is one of the best (worst?) ways of getting infected.

For if you see me lying around,
Unbelievable pain will take you down.

> The first part of this line may refer to the [persistence of strep on surfaces](http://iai.asm.org/content/early/2013/12/17/IAI.01310-13.abstract?sid=0568ac24-f841-419e-b49e-b6df59af528b), and most strep infections are painful; additionally, if you *see* the bacteria, as in get it in your eyes, and it infects the cornea it can cause a [painful eye infection](http://www.cnib.ca/en/your-eyes/eye-conditions/pages/infections-0208.aspx).

Let's, not forget, if I touch you, you can't run away.

> Once the bacteria is on you, running won't shake it off (but a good wash with warm water and soap should).

Hints:

> You may get hot around me, Your hands and feet will plea.

=

> Strep infections are usually accompanied by a fever. One severe complication is [rheumatic fever, which causes pain in the wrists and ankles](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/rheumatic-fever/symptoms-causes/syc-20354588), and in one extreme case of strep infection that made the news last year, [a man had to have his feet and hands amputated](https://www.cnn.com/2017/03/16/health/strep-throat-amputation-septic-shock-michigan-bn/index.html).

Title: Don't confuse me with the one about chickens!

> A common variant of strep infection, especially among children, is [scarlet fever, which is commonly classed with chickenpox](http://www.valeofglamorgan.gov.uk/en/living/social_care/children_and_young_people/Family-Information-Service/providers_zone/Healthy-Childcare/Scarlet-Fever-and-Chickenpox.aspx) as a "common childhood rash" and may be mistaken for that disease by parents.

Comment: I'm sorry, this isn't right, though it is close. I'll add a second hint now

Comment: Ah, pretty sure I know, then. I don't know how to do the code answers, but is it [this](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hand-foot-and-mouth-disease/symptoms-causes/syc-20353035)? I considered that one, but thought the (visual) "pattern" fit better for this one.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is also a disease from the bible:

> Leprosy

And, while I considered foot-and-mouth disease, too, I felt only leprosy literally has the "if you see me lying around" element (leprosy blankets, clothing carried the disease)

As to the Chicken, I was thinking the riddle, not the pox.  You wouldn't want to cross a road to get to the leper colony...

EDIT AFTER HINTS:
Well, anyway, before the hints, I liked my answer better than the accepted one, but those hints make it wrong, since if anything, children fared slightly better . . .

Comment: No, that's not it, sorry.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation as to why do you think this is the answer? Look at the other answers for an example (you don't need to include the hints).

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Thx, have done so.  Joe-You-Know if only you hadn't given the hints (which I hadn't seen when i answered . . .)

Answer (score 1):

> Boils

Pain is what I will attack you with,
A plague that appears once, what a myth.

> One of the ten biblical plagues to attack Egypt

In your throat I'll sequester,
Now in your hands I'll fester.

> Two places you can get boils

For if you see me lying around,
Unbelievable pain will take you down.

> Painful? yes

Let's, not forget, if I touch you, you can't run away.

> Because the infection is in your skin

Hint- You may get hot around me,
Your hands and feet will plea.

> Boiling? Hot?

Comment: This isn't the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse me with the one about chickens!

> Cowpox?  A viral skin infection caused by the cowpox or catpox virus.

Pain is what I will attack you with,
 A plague that appears once, what a myth.

> Causes muscle aches and pains.  The common misconception is that you can only catch these viruses once.

In your throat I'll sequester,
 Now in your hands I'll fester.

> Starts with a cough and runny nose, and the primary symptom: localized, pustular lesions generally found on the hands and limited to the site of introduction

For if you see me lying around,
 Unbelievable pain will take you down.

> If you see the ulcerous pustules lying around (on your skin), it's going to be painful?

Let's, not forget, if I touch you, you can't run away.

> It's an infection spread by physical contact (usually with cows or cats).

What am I?

Hint

You may get hot around me,
 Your hands and feet will plea.

> High fever is another symptom.

Hint 2:

A disease commonly found in children,
 Sores will most always afflict them.

> Kids are more likely to get this than adults.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> The Bubonic Plague (black plague)

**A plague that appears once, what a myth.**

> It occurred multiple times in history over a few centuries if I recall

**In your throat I'll sequester**

> Caused issues withe the throat glands to the point they'd rupture out of the victim's body

Now in your hands I'll fester.

> Caused gangrene on the hands.

For if you see me lying around,Unbelievable pain will take you down.

> The reference to the rats carrying the virus

Unbelievable pain will take you down.

> Fever, swollen glands etc

Let's, not forget, if I touch you, you can't run away.

> People were bedridden

Comment: I'm sorry, this isn't the right answer. Also, I don't see where you tied this to the hints.

Comment: Ah well, it was worth a try, thanks anyway. Guess my answer was rushed and a bit too abstract. I'll take my time next time.